# Jogl 2.2.1 working tutorial for windows?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, jogl, shapes

i followed those steps in order to setup and create my first project:
[setup](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial) 
[tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/JOGL2.0.html)

Here is the problematic code:

## main class:

```
/**
 * 
 */

package name.wadewalker.tutorial;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;

/**
 * @author PTOSH
 *
 */
public class openGL{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    GLU glu;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLProfile.initSingleton();
        GLCapabilities CAPS = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        GLCanvas CANVAS = new GLCanvas(CAPS);
        CANVAS.addGLEventListener(new newLstn());
        Frame FRAME = new Frame("AWT WINDOW TEST");
        FRAME.setSize(1300, 700);
        FRAME.add(CANVAS);
        FRAME.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent E){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        FRAME.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

## GLEventListener :

```
package name.wadewalker.tutorial;

import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.fixedfunc.GLMatrixFunc;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;

public class newLstn  implements GLEventListener {
    private GL2 gl;
    private GLU glu;    
    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f,0f);

        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
          // Font-face triangle
          gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
          gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
//        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green
          gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
//        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue
          gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);

          // Right-face triangle
//        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
          gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
//        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue
          gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
//        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green
          gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);

          // Back-face triangle
//        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
//        gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
//        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green
//        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
//        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue
//        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
//   
//        // Left-face triangle
//        gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
//        gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
//        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue
//        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
//        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green
//        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glFlush();

          // ----- Render the Pyramid -----
          gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // reset the model-view matrix
          gl.glTranslatef(-0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // translate left and into the screen
          gl.glRotatef(15, -0.2f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // rotate about the y-axis
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          gl = arg0.getGL().getGL2();      // get the OpenGL graphics context
          glu = new GLU();                         // get GL Utilities
          gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // set background (clear) color
          gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);      // set clear depth value to farthest
          gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enables depth testing
          gl.glEnable(GL.GL_CULL_FACE_MODE);
          gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL);  // the type of depth test to do
          gl.glHint(GL.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST); // best perspective correction
//        gl.glShadeModel(0); // blends colors nicely, and smoothes out lighting

    }
    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
            int arg4) {
//      float red = 0.0f; float green = 0.0f; float blue = 0.0f;
////
////         gl = arg0.getGL().getGL2();
////
////         gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
////
//       gl.glPointSize(5.0f);
//
//       for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
//
//       red -= .09f; green -= .12f; blue -= .15f;
//
//       if (red < 0.15) red = 1.0f; if (green < 0.15) green = 1.0f; if (blue < 0.15) blue = 1.0f;
//
//       gl.glColor3f(red, green, blue);
//       gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS); gl.glVertex2i((i*10), 150); gl.glEnd(); }
//       TODO Auto-generated method stub
        glu.gluPerspective(45.0, 15, 0.1, 100.0); // fovy, aspect, zNear, zFar
    }   
}
```

I took the source code from the tutorial and modified it, my purpose is to start drawing simple 3d shapes. Problem when I execute the code, it is not rendering depth apparently. I also noticed that the tutorial was for JOGL 2.0 and some parts of the code is not working any more like : "gl.glHint(GL.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);"
so I have to delete or comment this part of the code to see the shape in 2D.
Please if someone can show me a path to a good update tutorial, or give me some help understanding the issues I'm facing.
Thank you for your help and the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your display function has the lines:

```
    gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

This will reset both the modelview and the projection matrix to identity, so in the following, you draw directly in clip space. This means that there will be no perspective effect at all.

In your `reshape` callback, you have

```
    glu.gluPerspective(45.0, 15, 0.1, 100.0); // fovy, aspect, zNear, zFar
```

which is meant to set up some perspective transform. But it has no effect as you overwrite that matrix in the display function. However, you also use it wrong. `gluPerspective()` will *multiply* the top matrix fo the *currently selected matrix stack* by some perspective transform.

What you should do is something like

```
    gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(45.0, 15, 0.1, 100.0); // fovy, aspect, zNear, zFar
    gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

in the reshape function and completely remove the

```
    gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

from the display function.

However, this will not give the result that you might expect. Since you draw your triangles partly out of the frustum, then.

Your display function ends with

```
      gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // reset the model-view matrix
      gl.glTranslatef(-0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // translate left and into the screen
      gl.glRotatef(15, -0.2f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // rotate about the y-axis
```

This code does not do anything at all. You completely have misunderstood how openGL works. It does not manage 3D objects for you, which you can later shift around in the world. It is a rendering API. And OpenGL is designed as a state machine. You set some rendering state, which affects the restulst of the *draw calls*. Here, you set some rendering state (the modelview matrix), but you draw nothing while this state is in effect. You must make those transforms *before* you issue the draw cals of the objects you want to appear transformed that way.

Note that all the things I meantioned so far are *correctly* used in the tutorial you linked.

Another big issue with this is that you should be aware that this code totally relies on *deprecated* GL. In modern GL, almost all of the GL functions you use here are gone. If you are learning OpenGL nowadays, you really should consider learning the modern way (which is not so modern anymore, we have the programmable pipeline now for a decade).

Comment: I agree with derhass, Greg86 doesn't really understand OpenGL and succeeded in breaking a working code example.

Comment: Thank you for bringing light into my way derhass, do you have some useful sources to learn the proper and modern way of coding openGL? And yes, I'm learning and making mistakes, I apologize for that.

Comment: @Greg86: YOu don't need to apologize. And I also did not intend to offend you with my answer. As far as modern OpenGL is considered, the tutorials [arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) and [open.gl](http://open.gl) are typically referred to as good. They do not deal with java, tough. But actually, the GL part is not that much different. However, dealing with pointers and C data types will be some issue. I don't know a good java tutorial for modern GL.

Comment: @derhass: Hi, I continued to look after good resources in JOGL I found some examples in [this git](https://github.com/elect86/modern-jogl-examples/tree/master/modern-jogl-examples). Anyway does some list of deprecated or migration exists ? From gl2 to gl3 ... ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just look at the API documentation. When a method is in GL4bc or GL3bc but not in GL3 or GL4, it means that it is deprecated. You can look at some modern examples based on JOGL here: https://github.com/elect86/modern-jogl-examples